# How to make an array of points using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I use JavaScript and Chartjs library to draw charts. I store points data in JSON:

`"Chart1":{"1": "4","4": "4","10": "4"}`

To draw charts correctly I need to provide input like that:

`data:[{x:1,y:4},{x:4,y:4},{x:10,y:4}]`.

I tried do this this way:

```
var userData = JSON.parse('{"Chart1":{"1": "4","4": "4","10": "4"}}');
var MyKey = [Object.keys(userData['Chart1'])];
var MyVal = [Object.values(userData['Chart1'])];
var POINTS = []; //I tried also {}
for(b=0; b <= MyKey.length; b++)
{
   POINTS.push({x:MyKey[b],y:MyVal[b]}); 
}
```

and then in config variable:

```
data:[POINTS]
```

but the output is:

```
[
   0:
   {
      x:["1","4","10"]
      y:["4","4","4"]
   }
   1:
   {
      x:undefined
      y:undefined
   }
}
```

f
So how I should do this correctly?

EDIT:
I corrected json string, I pasted it wrong, it's only a typo but thank you all for vigiliance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()`

```js
var userData = JSON.parse('{ "Chart1":{"1": "4","4": "4","10": "4"} }');
const data = Object.entries(userData['Chart1']).map(([x, y]) => ({ x, y }));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost works, but it gives output {x:"1", y:"4"} instead {x:1, y:4}, how can I parse this to int?

Answer (score 2):

1. Some characters were missing from the json string in your example.
2. `Object.keys` and `Object.values` return arrays, don't enclose them in `[]`.
3. You're storing strings, but your points probably need numbers for `x` and `y`. You can do the conversion with a `+` operator (or `parseInt` or `Number`).

```js
var userData = JSON.parse('{"Chart1":{"1": "4","4": "4","10": "4"}}');
var MyKey = Object.keys(userData['Chart1']);
var MyVal = Object.values(userData['Chart1']);
var POINTS = [];
for (b = 0; b < MyKey.length; b++) {
  POINTS.push({
    x: +MyKey[b],
    y: +MyVal[b]
  });
}
console.log(POINTS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Object.entries to get the keyPair value and then map it so that x = key and y = value.

```
const x = {Chart1:{"1": "4","4": "4","10": "4"}};

const chartKeyValuePair = Object.entries(x.Chart1);
const xy = chartKeyValuePair.map(([key, value]) => {return {x:key, y: value}});
console.log(xy);
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost works, but it gives output {x:"1", y:"4"} instead {x:1, y:4}, how can I parse this to int?

Comment: Use parseInt: ```return {x:parseInt(key), y: parseInt(value)};```

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating it! If you use a `for...in` loop, you get the key of each property in the data, and you can use that to refer to the value. No need for Object.keys etc. Demo:

```js
var userData = JSON.parse('{"Chart1":{"1": "4","4": "4","10": "4"}}');
var POINTS = [];

for (key in userData.Chart1) {
  POINTS.push({
    x: key,
    y: userData.Chart1[key]
  });
}
console.log(POINTS);
```

N.B. You'll see I made an assumption about the real stucture of the `userData` JSON string, because what you've posted in the question isn't valid JSON and causes a script error.